# Nginx - Not seeing expected values for Host and X-Forwarded-For

Tags: nginx, asp.net

Running on a Windows 10 development machine and following the example here:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/linux-nginx?view=aspnetcore-3.0#configure-nginx

I have the following config in my nginx.conf file for one server.

```
server {
    listen      443 ssl;
    #listen     80;
    server_name local.example.domain.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass                    http://localhost:30004;   
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   Connection keep-alive;
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }

    ssl_certificate      ./certs/cert.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key  ./certs/key.pem;
}
```

However when I inspect the request headers received in the app, I just see (among other headers)

```
Host localhost:30004
X-Forwarded-For 127.0.0.1
```

I have looked at the documentation below which references proxy.conf but putting the same settings in a file with that name seems to have no effect either.

https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/full/

Am I doing something wrong or does this not work as I'm expecting?

Comment: How did you make the request that produces the output you showed? Did you reload nginx after applying the config?

Comment: The request was via a web browser using the URL https://local.example.domain.com - as nginx intercepts the request and forwards on, I would expect it to forward the x-forward-header

Comment: What is the IP address of `local.example.domain.com` you used when testing? Was the web browser running on a different computer than the web server?

Comment: 127.0.0.1, no everything is on the same machine

Comment: I forgot to ask, what is the result you are expecting here? I cannot see that in the question, so the question cannot be answered.

Comment: I'm expecting to see the host header value as local.example.domain.com